# Error when i disable gc

Tags: garbage-collection, nim-lang

When i try to execute nim to run without a garbage collector with `--gc:none`, i receive the following error message:

`Error: system module needs 'initStackBottomWith'`

Since i have found 0 references in the manual and nimc documentation, What does it mean and how do i solve it? I have tried putting everything inside a main proc and calling it like this:

```
proc main =
  let noGarbage = 1 + 2

main()
```

(And i dont know what more i have to write to meet SO's quality standards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has been solved already [here](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/commit/54fdeb4f76e0fc1e07332e2d4f0b00ff014d4f5f)